# Check and avoid explicit content on blog android app

Tags: java, android, api, blogs

I am developing a Blog kinda app where a user can upload images, videos, text, etc.
My problem is that I wanted to stop the users from uploading any explicit content. I need to check whether the image or text contained with any explicit or bad content. Till now I am not able to check if the text contains any explicit contents. In this, I compare the textual words with my database word dictionary. But I feel it is not a perfect solution as the number of words are too many. I wanted to know if this kind of checking is feasible and if it is not possible to do so, then any suggestions that I should follow and most importantly in the case of images. I am ready to use any API if it exist for such problems.

If there are any specific libraries in other platforms can also be helpful for reference purpose.

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. ` ... when your bounty is over the question will most probably closed as off topic (the bounty prevents that at the moment).

Comment: Machine learning is hard to achieve specially when you have a limited time. Also you need to train your classifiers well so that you will see a less number of false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to remove spam it is a nice to consider [Akismet](https://akismet.com/development/api/). (Wordpress installations come with default integration.) There is an another widely used one called [SpamWipe](http://www.spamwipe.com/api.html).

If you would like to check Plagiarism, there are other tools like the one that [small seo tools](http://smallseotools.com/plagiarism-checker-api/) is providing. You can take a look at [copyleaks.com](https://api.copyleaks.com/) too.

There is a good list for API-s to use in your case:

> http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-18-apis-to-protect-your-site/

Of course you could use this kind of API-s in your application.